# How conenct Philips Hue, CC2531 Zigbee USB Dongle and Java

Tags: java, zigbee, philips-hue

I have USB Zigbee dongle and Philips Hue bulbs. I want use my USB dongle like coordinator or use like Living Color Remote. What I need to do? I google my problem several hours, but I don't have a lot of information about it.
Also I want to control bulbs with Java, for this I use zigbee4java, but my program doesn't work.
My code: `

```
package zigbee.test;
import org.bubblecloud.zigbee.ZigBeeApi;
import org.bubblecloud.zigbee.ZigBeeConsole;
import org.bubblecloud.zigbee.api.Device;
import org.bubblecloud.zigbee.api.cluster.general.Basic;

public class BootTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ZigBeeConsole.main(new String[]{
            "COM4", "11", "4954", "true"
    });
    }

}`
```

but I don't have any bulb in list of devices.

Comment: If you have bulbs, why are you not using the Philipps Hue Bridge? The bridge has a nice REST API, which can be used in any language, e.g. Java.

Answer (score 1):

If you bought the hue bulbs in pack of three with the bridge then you need to factory reset them with a living remote:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qh9HBCbJ-fs

When the bulbs are in factory reset state they will automatically join your Zigbee network provided that the dongle has firmware with security enabled and correct channel. If I recall correctly the default channel for the bulbs is 11 after factory reset but I am not 100% sure of that.

Some FAQ related to zigbee4java can be found here if you have trouble with the library itself:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/zigbee4java

Answer (score 0):

Since you are looking specifically to control Philips Hue, you may as well take a look at [kappa.io](http://kappa.io). It is a framework of ZigBee coordinator that runs on Raspberry Pi and CC2531 usb dongle.

Out of box, the pre-built image is able to take control of ZHA/ZLL bulbs, e.g. factory reset, adjust brightness, adjust color.